# Package for generating getters and setters in sublime 3

Tags: java, package, sublimetext3

Anyone aware of a package for generating getter and setter methods in java for Sublime Text 3?

[QuickJava](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/QuickJava) seems to have been taken down by its author.

Comment: Not what you are asking, but I like [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) to avoid the tedious job of writing getters/setters.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [`Javatar`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javatar), which does its best to turn Sublime into a Java IDE. I haven't used it much, since Java isn't my main development language (yay Python!), and scanning through [the docs](https://javatar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) didn't specifically mention getters/setters, but there may well be a snippet included that does that. Alternatively, you could [write your own](https://javatar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javatar_snippets.html).

As far as QuickJava is concerned, you could try contacting the [author](https://github.com/jameshiew) and see if he has an archive of it that you could get. It's worth a shot, I suppose.